# How to delete fragments related to FragmentStatePagerAdapter by deleting the parent fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a TabsFragment, that is used to display FragmentStatePagerAdapter. To display tabs, I firstly create a TabsFragment, which creates multiple fragments, stored in tabs. The problem is, when I destroy a TabsFragment and create a new one, tab fragments created by previous TabsFragment are kept in memory for some reason. So does look like my TabsFragment class:

```
public class TabsFragment extends AbstractFragment {
    public static final String TAG = "Tabs_Fragment";
    private ViewPagerParallax viewPager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPagerParallax)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.set_max_pages(CustomFragmentPagerAdapter.PAGE_COUNT);
        viewPager.setBackgroundAsset(R.drawable.background);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
        PagerSlidingTabStrip tabsStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabsStrip.setViewPager(viewPager);
        return view;
    }
    ...
}
```

Like this I replace my TabsFragment with some other fragment:

```
   public void transactOver(AbstractFragment what, int direction) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, what, what.getClassTag());
    ft.commit();
   }
```

Where **R.id.fragment_content** is a framelayout, that stores my fragmens. **CustomFragmentPagerAdapter** is coded as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Finished up changing

```
 viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomFragmentPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
```

with

```
 viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomFragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
```